# Parsing a CSV: Edge Cases

Tags: parsing, csv, dataformat

*Disclaimer:* I'm not actually parsing a CSV, but a CSV-like format; I'm not interested in using a pre-built library.

What is the proper way to parse the following 2 lines?:

```
a,b"c"d,e
a,"bc"d,e
```

i.e., (a) with quotes in the middle of a value, and (b) with a quote at the start, but no end quote immediately before the next value.

I can't figure out how I should handle these cases (that would be the most intuitive).

---

My thoughts are that (a) should be parsed as `a`,`b"c"d`,`e` (quotes left in), and (b) should be parsed the same way, `a`,`"bc"d`,`e`. But then let me introduce a 3rd case, `a,"b,c"d,e` -- do we split on that 2nd comma between "b" and "c" or not?

Comment: Ultimately it depends on what exactly you allow between the separators - and how you want it to be interpreted. There's not a proper way, you have to define the rules.

Comment: @moodywoody: Well, how do other parsers handle these cases? As a user, if you were entering a comma-separated list of tags (similar to SO's tags but with a comma delimiter), what behaviour would you expect?

Comment: Me personally, when it comes to quotations and such, I don't expect anything - I ask for a definition (I know it's a bit of a cop out, but I like my problems to be "well defined"). Anyhow, you may find these two links dealing with perl and csv files interesting        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633607/how-can-i-parse-quoted-csv-in-perl-with-a-regex.                                             http://www.en8848.com.cn/Reilly%20Books/perl3/cookbook/ch01_16.htm .

Comment: `"([^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*)"` -- that's a pretty sweet regex. I didn't think you could parse strings with a regex and do the escapes properly (have to make sure there's an odd number); I asked about it earlier to no avail. I'll have to dig into that a bit deeper. I've never used perl, but I think I get the jist of it.

Comment: If I'm reading that Perl solution correctly, `"bc"d` would be omitted completely, because there's no comma immediately after the end quote. I think I kind of like that... it's malformed, so it doesn't get included, but the whole CSV doesn't blow up. http://i.imgur.com/RFWoq.png

Comment: As said before, there are several "solutions" which depend on how you expect the output. If you have access to a copy of "Mastering regular expressions" by Friedl - there's a whole chapter about this class of problem (6.7. Unrolling the loop)

Comment: Now that I've thought about this a bit more... I think we can simplify the string matching a fair bit yet: `"(\\.|[^"\\])*"`

Comment: I understand you are not interested in a pre-built library-- hear me out-- check out https://github.com/liquidaty/zsv, which handles all these edge cases the same way Excel does and has built-in options to modify separators etc. The source code is there if you want to further modify to suit your purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would parse it if you want to be consistent with Excel:

input:

```
a,b"c"d,e
a,"bc"d,e
a,"b,c"d,e
```

parsed (in JSON):

```
[
  ["a", "b\"c\"d", "e"],
  ["a", "bcd", "e"],
  ["a","b,cd", "e"]
]
```

The parsing logic is:

- if the first char of the row, or immediately after a comma, is a dbl-quote, then:

  - treat everything following it as "quoted" until you reach the closing quote (of course, treat two-quotes-in-a-row as an escaped dbl-quote). Remove the opening and the closing quote from the cell value
  - after the "end quote" has been reached, include anything after the end quote in the cell value as a literal value, until a comma or newline has been reached
- otherwise, treat everything after the comma as a literal value, until a comma or newline has been reached

Note that this means that if you have a space after a cell-delimiting comma, followed by a dbl-quote, you get a different result than if you have no space after the comma (followed by a dbl-quote)

Answer (score 0):

here is the part of my method (C#) to spit csv to html table - it has such comma parsing:

```
string[] cells = line.Split(','); // empty cells needed as well
bool noComma = true;

for (int i = 0; i < cells.Length; i++)
{
    string cellI = cells[i];
    int numberOfDoubleQuote = cellI.Count(f => f == '"');
    // == 0 means comma in between quotes
    if (numberOfDoubleQuote == 1)
    {
        noComma = !noComma;
        if (!noComma)
            sLine += "<td>" + cellI;
        else
            sLine += "," + cellI + "</td>";
    }
    else
    {
        if (noComma)
            sLine += "<td>" + cellI + "</td>";
        else
            sLine += "," + cellI;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you essentially split on all commas and then "join" cells if they contain a single quote... but I don't think you've covered the cases very well. For example, how would it handle `a,b",c` ? If I'm reading this right, it would output `a`,`b",c` which seems wrong.