# Changing CSV file with regexes

Tags: regex, perl

Because meantime i wrote an answer to the [question, what got closed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28693766/734304) - trying to reword and re-ask it.

Having an CSV file with 180 milions records, with 5 columns as:

```
"c a","L G-3 (8) N (4th G P Q C- 4 R- 1 T H- 15.6 I- W 8.1) (B)","C & P_L",1,0
```

How to change it to the 3 column structure as:

```
"c a|L G-3 (8) N (4th G P Q C- 4 R- 1 T H- 15.6 I- W 8.1) (B)|C & P_L",1,0
```

e.g. need concatenate the colums 1,2,3 with `|` and print it as one column and leave other colums unchanged

Tried it with regexes:

```
cat RelatedKW.csv | perl -pe 's/(\|)/\//g'| perl -pe 's/("\s*"|"\s*"\s*\\n$)//g'| perl -pe 's/^,"|,,|"\s*,\s*\"/|/g' | perl -pe 's/\"(\d+),(\d+)\"/ |$1|$2/g' > newRKW4.csv`
```

Is here any better way?

Comment: Don't re-ask questions. Edit your previous question.

Answer (score 1):

You should generally avoid parsing CSVs with regex, as [Kent Fredric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15614/kent-fredric) explains in answer to [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/633646/176646):

> **Not using CPAN is really a recipe for disaster.**
>
> Please consider this before trying to write your own CSV implementation.
> Text::CSV is over a hundred lines of code, including fixed bugs and edge cases,
> and re-writing this from scratch will just make you learn how awful CSV can be the hard way.

It is **really** bad practice trying to parse CSVs with regexes, because for example, you need to handle:

- escaped quotes
- escaped separator characters
- fields containing the delimiter

and so on, all of which Text::CSV will handle for you.

Here's a solution that uses Text::CSV. I'm not a Perl expert, so the following code may be missing some things, but it is probably better than using regexes:

```
perl -MText::CSV_XS -E '$csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ eol => $/ }); $csv->print(*STDOUT, [join(q{|}, @$row[0..2]), @$row[3..4]]) while ($row = $csv->getline(*STDIN))' < csv
```

**Input:**

```
"c a","L G-3 (8) N (4th G P Q C- 4 R- 1 T H- 15.6 I- W 8.1) (B)","C & P_L",1,0
```

**Output:**

```
"c a|L G-3 (8) N (4th G P Q C- 4 R- 1 T H- 15.6 I- W 8.1) (B)|C & P_L",1,0
```

Some potential problems: it doesn't handles escaping of the `|` character, if there are any in the input, no error handling, etc. For a better solution you need to write a full-featured Perl script and not a one-liner.

Comment: You might be surprised but regexes are not always right tool for the job, and CSV parsing is contrary to popular belief *not* trivial. So there are choices, either to reinvent your own (broken?) wheel, or to use right tool for the job.

Comment: I understand that you're trying to respond directly to the OP of a question that was already closed, but the "dialog" (e.g. "On the other side, I understand you. You're probably not an programmer.") doesn't really make sense here. I've cleaned it up so your answer will actually make sense to other users. Instead of posting a duplicate question, I think you should have edited the original so it's not too broad and then people could have voted to re-open if they thought the question had value for the site.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yeah. I understand - and you're right - thank you for the edit. (Sorry, I only get a bit upset by some comments and need cooled down). Editing the original question and vote for reopen would be sure the best way.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts on this topic and the fact that you suggested `Text::CSV` +1

Comment: @Сухой27 I wouldn't be surprised - as you can see yourself, i'm using Text::CSV - so, I don't understanding your comment - what is _reinvented_ in my (as you said - my broken?) solution? Could you be please more specific?

Comment: @kobame I was referring to regex only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is exactly like what it is this should work

```
$line =~ s-\",\"-|-g;
```