# String to split a complicated string in Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
'som,ething', another, 'thin#'g', 'her,e', gggh*
```

I am trying to get it to split on the commas that are NOT in the elements, like this:

```
'som,ething'
another
'thin#'g'
'her,e'
gggh*
```

I am using `parse_line(q{,}, 1, $string)` but it seems to fail when the string has single quotes in it. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @vks This is NOT a duplicate. First of all, the question is for Perl, second of all the question states that the single quotes within the string are the issue - not the commas.

Comment: Do you actually have mismatched quotes - `'thin'g',` - that makes the problem considerably harder (how would you tell which field the following comma belongs to?)

Comment: @werhgvfwe5r, all you really need is the regexp from linked question. The Perl wrapper around it is absolutely trivial.

Comment: @Sobrique, yes, sadly the quotes are mismatched. However, I made a small mistake in my original question. The quotes that are in quotes are usually escaped with a special character (`#`). Updating the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to parse comma-separated values. The answer is to use [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/release/Text-CSV_XS) since that handles the various weird cases you're likely to find in the data. See [How can I parse quoted CSV in Perl with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633607/how-can-i-parse-quoted-csv-in-perl-with-a-regex)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = q{'som,ething', another, 'thin'g', 'her,e', gggh*};
my @splitted = split(/,(?=\s+)/, $string);
print $_."\n" foreach @splitted;
```

Output:

```
'som,ething'
 another
 'thin'g'
 'her,e'
 gggh*
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/I5cNjh)

Comment: Uh, while it "works" with this particular string, it obviously doesn't match task described in question: `q{'som , ething', another, 'thin'g', 'her,e', gggh*}` = fail.

Comment: Forgot to mention that inner quotes are escaped by a hash (`#`). I assume that might make things easier.

Comment: This solution also assumes that the commas are all followed by a space. It's possible there is none: `a word,'another',field, here`

Answer (score -1):

Using `split` is not the way to go. If you are sure your string is well formatted using a global match is more simple, example:

```
my $line = "'som,ething', another , 'thin#'g', 'her,e' , gggh*";

my @list = $line =~ /\s*('[^#']*(?:#.[^#']*)*+'|[^,]+(?<=\S))\s*/g;

print join("|", @list);
```

*(the `(?<=\S)` is only here to trim items on the right)*